# How can I subtract two dataframes based on a column mapping?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to subtract df A from df B where the column mapping is based on a 3rd mapping data frame.
In this example, B should be subtracted from x1 and A should be subtracted from x2.

This can be done with loops and some other dirty methods, but I was wondering if there is a more concise way to do that.

Dataframe a

| date | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/31/2019 | 0.1 | 0.4 |
| 12/31/2020 | 0.3 | 0.6 |

Dataframe b

| date | x1 | x2 | x3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/31/2019 | 1.0 | 0.8 | 1.0 |
| 12/31/2020 | 0.4 | 0.7 | 1.5 |

Dataframe c

| From | To |
| --- | --- |
| x1 | B |
| x2 | A |
| x3 | A |

Required result

| date | x1 | x2 | x3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/31/2019 | 0.6 | 0.7 | 0.9 |
| 12/31/2020 | -0.2 | 0.4 | 1.2 |

Comment: Forgot to mention that number of columns in DF B is bigger than the number of columns in DF A, but there will always be a 1 to 1 mapping between them. Editing the example accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `merge` before subtracting:

```
tmp = pd.merge(dfa, dfb, on='date')
dfb[dfc['From']] = tmp[dfc['From']].values - tmp[dfc['To']].values
print(dfb)

# Output:
         date   x1   x2   x3
0  12/31/2019  0.6  0.7  0.9
1  12/31/2020 -0.2  0.4  1.2
```

Comment: @Gal. I updated my solution. Can you check it please? Since you have a same `To` (A) for multiple `From` (x2, x3), the solution of @QuangHoang can't work as is.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rename` to temporary rename the column and subtract. Assuming the `date` is your index:

```
a - b.rename(columns=c.set_index('From')['To'])
```

Output:

```
               A    B
date
12/31/2019  -0.7 -0.6
12/31/2020  -0.4  0.2
```

Comment: FYI. the code raises a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`. I suppose you consider `date` column as index? And you should probably swap `a` and `b`. Check the expected output (columns are `x1` and `x2`)

Comment: @Corralien agreed. I like this solution, However it mixed up to column names. How can I change it to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Set the date index on the data frames, create a Series from the third dataframe; map df1's columns with the Series map and finally do the subtraction:

```py
df1 = df1.set_index('date')

df2 = df2.set_index('date')

df3 = df3.set_index('To').From

df1.columns = df1.columns.map(df3)

df2 - df1

             x1   x2
date
12/31/2019  0.6  0.7
12/31/2020 -0.2  0.4
```